# Are websockets implemented in SignalR+UWP?

Tags: .net, uwp, signalr

In the following documentation from 8 months ago Microsoft claims that Websocket usage by SignalR in a UWP/.NET application is not implemented:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

This is surprising as the UWP platform has an implementation of the WebSocket standard. I wish to use SignalR for duplex communication between a UWP application running on a HoloLens (the client) and a WPF application (the server). Rather than assuming that SignalR can use the WebSockets transport layer in this configuration I thought someone in the community might know for sure. The multiple frameworks and documentation are making it difficult to figure out for those new to this sort of thing.

Comment: You asked a very strange question. How do you want SignalR on UWP? SignalR client or server? Make that clear and then the question would be clear to answer. The page you referred to belongs to ASP.NET 4.x's SignalR which is pretty old of course, as now SignalR on .NET Core 2.1 is preferred. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: if you edit your question and include what you typed above, I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: @LKeene The doc seems already clarified that websocket as a transport is not supported on UWP/.NET. Why websocket is required here? Also what about using UWP/JS app if websocket is required? By the way, for UWP/.NET usage, you can report it to here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform